# .Net 7 Added/Non added Identity scaffolding pages still works after page removed

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I am trying to test a blazor server app with a custom `IdentityUser`. After creating the project with the individual account. I also used add new scaffolding items and selected Identity and selected certain pages. ForgetPassword, Profile Edit (Manage/Index) but in the _ManageNav.cshtml there are other links eg. Email, TwoFactorAuthentication. Even though these pages are not in the folder structure they are still working when I visit them. As they are not in the projects I cannnot change them as well.

First question, even though this is a blazor project Identity pages are added as razor pages (cshtml files) (well the naming and extension convention is another subject).

***Edit***: Found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69320133/604876) for the first question so please ignore.

Second, all these behavior are they expected?

Third, as I don't want these pages I expect them to return 404, and the only solution I can find is adding all the pages (there are a lot) and change their `OnGet` method to return `NotFound()` result. Any suggestions? or how it should be done?